# CheckBox Selection in JTable

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application

I want, in a JTable, has a column that when it is clicked, a JPanel to appear with the names of all the columns, and it can select (with JCheckBox) which we want to continue in the JTable. It would be a column with "#".

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It is better to tell what you have tried so far? then it is easy for others to help you

Answer (score 1):

Just create such a column in your data model implementation, with a custom artificial data object. Then register an editor (setDefaultEditor) in the jtable to show a checkbox or open a dialog with a checkbox. based on the user selection you may then alter your model (add or remove columns) and fire an according changed event.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for but maybe you can use the [Table Column Manager](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/table-column-manager/).

The `Table Column Manager` manages which columns are visible in the table. You invoke the `Table Column Manager` by right clicking on any column in the column header. You are presented with a popup menu that uses check boxes to hide/show columns.